# how to connect database from wamp to workbench

Tags: mysql, wamp, mysql-workbench

I am trying to read tables from WAMP in MySQL Workbench.
I searched a bit and tried them but nothing worked.
Dose anybody know how to do that?
Thank you advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/index.html.

I recommend you go through it. Very nicely explained.